# Dialog opens blank

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i recently switched to AndEngine to play a little bit around with this engine. Before the switch i already implemented a `DialogFragment` wich worked just fine. Now i wanted to "port" this `DialogFragment` to the AndEngine. Because there is no support for the FragmentActivity (as far as i know) in AndEngine i decided to change my code to a simple `Dialog` instead. 
Now the dialog opens just fine, but is completely blank. Just a small black rectangle with a border.

I cannot see what could be wrong with my code..maybe you can help.

```
public class SimpleDialog extends Dialog {

    final long number;
    Context context;

    public SimpleDialog (Context context, long number) {
        super(context);
        this.number = number;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = ResourceManager.getInstance().activity.getLayoutInflater();

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.logindialog, null);

        final EditText editTextUserName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.usernameToSubmit);
        final EditText editTextPassword = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.passwordToSubmit);

        TextView numberText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.numberText);
        highscoreText.setText("Number: " + Long.toString(number));

        builder.setView(view)
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.login_submit, null)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.login_abort, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        final AlertDialog d = builder.create();

        d.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Button b = d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);

                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
```

This is how i open the Dialog:

```
ResourceManager.getInstance().activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new SimpleDialog(ResourceManager.getInstance().activity, number).show();
    }

});
```

if you also need my layout please let me know.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `AlertDialog.Builder` rather than modifying your own instance of the Dialog. `AlertDialog.Builder` creates its own AlertDialog, and modifies *that* instance instead. It does not, and will not affect your `SimpleDialog` instance.

Since you are already using the Builder to create your Dialog I don't see a need for extending `Dialog` itself. Why not move the Builder code into a method or a wrapper class, and call the method directly?

Something like this:

```
public class DialogRunner {

  public static void createAndShowDialog (Context context, long number){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from (context);

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.logindialog, null);

    final EditText editTextUserName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.usernameToSubmit);
    final EditText editTextPassword = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.passwordToSubmit);

    TextView numberText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.numberText);
    highscoreText.setText("Number: " + Long.toString(number));

    builder.setView(view)
      .setNegativeButton(R.string.login_submit, null)
      .setPositiveButton(R.string.login_abort, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dismiss();
      }
    });

    final AlertDialog d = builder.create();

    d.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

      @Override
      public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        Button b = d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

          }
        });

      }
    });

    d.show();
  }
}
```

To run:

```
ResourceManager.getInstance().activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        DialogRunner.createAndShowDialog(ResourceManager.getInstance().activity, number);
    }

});
```

Comment: .setNegativeButton(R.string.login_submit, null)
      .setPositiveButton(R.string.login_abort, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { should be       .setNegativeButton(R.string.login_abort, null)
      .setPositiveButton(R.string.login_submit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {